# My professor says that this equation in a finite field has a solution but I don't think it does.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

More than likely it is I who is mistaken, but is there a chance that my professor made a mistake in the following problem? We are tasked with:

Let $p = 3$. We do not have an element of order $5$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so let $\zeta$ be an ("imaginary") solution of $x^5 - 1 = 0$. Use SAGE to find the coefficients $a_k \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $(a_0 + a_1\zeta + a_2\zeta^2 + a_3\zeta^3)^2 = 2$.

Now using brute force, we only have to check $3^4$ possibilities since each of $a_0, a_1, a_2,$ and $a_3$ may take on one of 3 values in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

So consider:

```
for i in Integers(3):
    for j in Integers(3):
        for k in Integers(3):
            for l in Integers(3):
                a = i;
                b = j;
                c = k;
                d = l;
                print expand((a + b*z + c*z^2 + d*z^3)^2);
0
z^6
z^6
z^4
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^4
z^6 + z^5 + z^4
z^4
z^6 + z^5 + z^4
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^4
z^2
z^6 + 2*z^4 + z^2
z^6 + z^4 + z^2
z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^3 + z^2
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2
z^4 + z^3 + z^2
z^6 + z^5 + z^3 + z^2
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^4 + z^3 + z^2
z^2
z^6 + z^4 + z^2
z^6 + 2*z^4 + z^2
z^4 + z^3 + z^2
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^4 + z^3 + z^2
z^6 + z^5 + z^3 + z^2
z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^3 + z^2
1
z^6 + 2*z^3 + 1
z^6 + z^3 + 1
z^4 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^4 + z^2 + 1
z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2 + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + 1
z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^3 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + 2*z + 1
z^4 + z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^4 + z^3 + z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^4 + z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^3 + z + 1
z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + z^3 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
1
z^6 + z^3 + 1
z^6 + 2*z^3 + 1
z^4 + z^2 + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + 1
z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2 + 1
z^4 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + z^3 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
z^4 + z^3 + z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^3 + z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^4 + z + 1
z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^4 + 2*z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^4 + z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + 2*z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^4 + 2*z^3 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + 2*z + 1
z^6 + 2*z^5 + z^3 + 2*z + 1
```

It appears that we can reach 1, but not 2. Now if we make use of the fact that $\zeta^4 = -\zeta^3 - \zeta^2 - \zeta - 1$ and $\zeta^5 = 1$, we can make the following substitutions:

```
for i in Integers(3):
    for j in Integers(3):
        for k in Integers(3):
            for l in Integers(3):
                a = i;
                b = j;
                c = k;
                d = l;
                print expand(2*b*c + 2*a*d - c^2 - 2*b*d)*z^3 + (b^2 + 2*a*c - c^2 - 2*b*d)*z^2 + (2*a*b + d^2 - 2*c^2 - 4*b*d)*z + (a^2 + 2*c*d);

0
z
z
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + z
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 2
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + z
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2*z + 2
z^2
z^3 + 2*z^2
2*z^3 + 2*z
z^3 + z
2*z^3 + z^2 + z + 2
2*z^2 + 1
z
z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2
z^2
2*z^3 + 2*z
z^3 + 2*z^2
z
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + 2
z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^3 + z
2*z^2 + 1
2*z^3 + z^2 + z + 2
1
2*z^3 + z + 1
z^3 + z + 1
2*z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^3 + z^2 + 2*z
z^2 + 2*z + 2
2*z^3 + z + 1
z^3 + 2*z + 2
2*z
z^2 + 2*z + 1
2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z + 1
z^3 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^3
z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 2
z^2 + 1
2*z^2 + 2
2*z
z^2 + z + 1
z^3 + 1
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^3 + z^2 + z
2*z^3 + 2*z + 2
z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 1
2*z^3 + z + 2
2*z^2 + 2*z
1
z^3 + z + 1
2*z^3 + z + 1
2*z^3 + z + 1
2*z
z^3 + 2*z + 2
2*z^3 + z^2 + z + 1
z^2 + 2*z + 2
z^3 + z^2 + 2*z
z^2 + z + 1
2*z^3 + 2*z^2 + z + 1
z^3 + 1
z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 1
2*z^2 + 2*z
2*z^3 + z + 2
2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
2*z^3 + 2*z + 2
z^3 + z^2 + z
z^2 + 2*z + 1
z + 1
2*z^2 + 2*z + 1
z^2 + 1
2*z
2*z^2 + 2
z^3 + 2*z^2 + 1
z^3 + z^2 + 2*z + 2
z^3
```

Once again we can reach $1$ but not $2$. Is there a lapse in my logic somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up while reducing your polynomials modulo $1 + \zeta + \zeta^2 + \zeta^3 + \zeta^4$, as you can see how your $\zeta^4$ ($4$th entry in the list) doesn't turn into $2z^3+2z^2+2z+2$.

Comment: I see my mistake now, I reduced incorrectly as you pointed out. After fixing it, I found the correct coefficients! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The field $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta)$ has $3^5=243$ elements and $3^5-1=2\cdot 11^2$ units, so there is no element of order $4$, which is what you're looking for, since $2=-1$ in characteristic $3$. So you are right, there is no solution.</s>

Edit: This is nonsense of course, the field has $3^4$ elements and $2^4\cdot 5$ units.